# As a cargo tech, what's the proper procedure to follow when someone requests supplies?

Tags: space-station-13

Too get to know the game I've been working as a simple cargo tech for the past few sessions. It took some getting used to but I've now figured out how to order new supplies and call for the supply shuttle.

On the station I'm playing the quartermaster doesn't seem to hang around much, so whenever people come to the cargo station with a request I just always approve it.

Is this actually the right procedure? Should I be asking for official approvals more often, and if so from who?

Comment: It's going to vary from server to server but there's nothing wrong with this approach if the QM doesn't mind and you don't give out inappropriate items to people, e.g. weapons to non-security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time, this is perfectly fine.  A lot of the supplies they will request are perfectly harmless, and you don't need to add extra red tape for things like a Corgi Crate.

If for any reason you suspect they might abuse their supplies, check their request for approval from their department head (Chief Medical Officer for Medical, Research Director for Science, Chief Engineer for Engineering, Head of Security for Security, Head of Personnel for all other departments, or Captain for the entire ship).

If they're filling out a request right then and there, and it has potential to be lethal, I usually ask them to get their department head to stamp and sign the form.  If it IS the department head, I usually just ask them to sign the order form.  This will keep you clear of suspicion should a crate full of energy guns find its way around the station.

---

Of course, just because you don't *have* to add red tape to menial orders, doesn't mean you can't do it anyway.  If you feel like it, or if they're there in person to make the request, you can ask them to explain their order to you, and usually they'll gladly oblige.  Not only will this teach you which departments need which materials, it will add a little roleplaying to your job, which is always worth the effort.